# How to iterate over nested classes/properties from Web API call in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently learning the basics of ASP.NET Core and C# and recently built a Blazor Server App to serve as a crude weather dashboard. After calling the desired weather web API in my web browser, I copied and pasted the returned raw data into my app through the 'paste JSON as classes' feature and  then edited down the classes I want to target into two separate models as follows:

```
public class WeatherForecastModel
{
public DayForecastModel[] daily { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class DayForecastModel
{
public int sunrise { get; set; }
public int sunset { get; set; }
public Temp temp { get; set; }
public Feels_Like feels_like { get; set; }
}

public class Temp
{
public float day { get; set; }
public float min { get; set; }
public float max { get; set; }
}
```

In my razor page, I am able to successfully iterate over properties in the DayForecastModel and display them in my table doing the following:

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var w in forecast.daily)
            {
            <tr>
                <th>@w.sunrise</th>
                <th>@w.sunset</th>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

for reference, my 'forecast' variable is defined elsewhere as follows:

```
forecast = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecastModel>("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=36.0999&lon=-80.2442&exclude={part}&appid={appid}&units=imperial");
```

What I can't figure out is how to access the properties contained in the 'Temp' class, which is itself contained inside the DayForecastModel class, so I can display things like 'day', 'min', and 'max'.

Apologies if this too convoluted of a question, I am very new to all of this. I'm more than happy to add any additional code that would help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
<tr>
  <th>@w.sunrise</th>
  <th>@w.sunset</th>
  <td>@w.temp?.day</td>
</tr>
```

The `?` in `w.temp?.day` allows for `temp == null`. If that is the case you have to fix it somwhere else.

HTML note: `<th>` is for headers, you probably want `<td>` instead.